# Change window menu's location

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows when you open a menu, its location on the screen depends on the location of its parent window and screen resolution. Ie when a menu does not fit the screen, then it moves to another side.
 How does this mechanism work in the OS? Is it possible to substitute the value of screen resolution, so that the window would consider that the screen is smaller than it actually is?

I want to make a drop-down and context menus to appear only in window area. Now I use CBThook and WndProc and recount the location of the menu that appears. Perhaps there is a way to make it easier?

Comment: Nice question. Here's your first +1 ;)

Comment: Why do people want to meddle with the platform? What's wrong with the native menus?

Comment: Tough to avoid wanting to mess with *everything* once you got global hooks figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TrackPopupMenuEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does allow you to specify a rectangle on the screen that the menu should **not** overlap, I guess that is sort of the opposite of what you want, but it is as close as you are going to get without horrible hacks.

Comment: There's also the various `ALIGN` flags - so you could work out the menu's size (use `GetMenuItemRect`), then position it manually by its edges so that it stays within the window. I guess that might work.